# System.StackOverFlowException was thrown during debugging but the line it breaks on is different each debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, monogame

I'm creating a fairly simple C# Monogame project using visual studios 2019. I am getting a stack overflow error but it breaks on random lines each time I debug. Sometimes it'll break just on a "{". I think I've had weird errors like this before that seem like something messed up in the lower level code I don't have access to. I've already tried clean code, rebuild project, closing solutions, unloading/reloading project, and restarting my pc. Can anyone help me out?

So I found which code block is breaking somehow.

```
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using System;

    namespace Project1
    {
         class Map
    {

    public Vector2 Player;
    public Vector2 Destination;
    public GameState gamestate = new GameState();
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Cols { get; set; }

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Texture2D texture;
    private Color[] colors;
    private bool[,] state;
    private bool[,] next_state;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Map(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int rows, int cols)
    {
        texture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, cols, rows);

        this.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;

        colors = new Color[rows * cols];

        state = new bool[rows, cols];
        next_state = new bool[rows, cols];

        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Cols = cols;

        Player = new Vector2(random.Next(Cols), random.Next(Rows));
        Destination = new Vector2(random.Next(Cols), random.Next(Rows));

        gamestate.Reset();
    }

    public void Randomize()
    {
        Player = new Vector2(random.Next(Cols), random.Next(Rows));
        Destination = new Vector2(random.Next(Cols), random.Next(Rows));

        for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
            {
                int ran = random.Next(3);

                if (ran == 1) next_state[r, c] = true;
                else next_state[r, c] = false;
            }
        }

        next_state[(int)Player.Y, (int)Player.X] = true;
        next_state[(int)Destination.Y, (int)Destination.X] = true;

        Apply();
    }

    int neighbors;
    public void Step()
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
            {
                neighbors = 0;

                if (r < Rows - 1 && state[r + 1, c]) neighbors++;
                if (c < Cols - 1 && state[r, c + 1]) neighbors++;
                if (r > 0 && state[r - 1, c]) neighbors++;
                if (c > 0 && state[r, c - 1]) neighbors++;

                if (r < Rows - 1 && c < Cols - 1 && state[r + 1, c 
           + 1]) neighbors++;
                if (r > 0 && c > 0 && state[r - 1, c - 1]) neighbors++;
                if (r < Rows - 1 && c > 0 && state[r + 1, c - 1]) neighbors++;
                if (r > 0 && c < Cols - 1 && state[r - 1, c + 1]) neighbors++;

                if (state[r, c] == true)
                {
                    if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3) 
                    next_state[r, c] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (neighbors == 3) next_state[r, c] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        gamestate.Moves++;

        Apply();
    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        int i = 0;

        state = next_state;

        for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
            {
                if (state[r, c] == true) colors[i] = Color.Black;
                else colors[i] = Color.White;

                if (state[r, c] == true && Player == new Vector2(c, r)) colors[i] = Color.Red;
                else if (state[r, c] == false && Player == new Vector2(c, r)) colors[i] = Color.Green;

                if (Destination == new Vector2(c, r)) colors[i] = Color.Blue;

                i++;
            }
        }

        texture.SetData(colors);

        if (Player == Destination)
        {
            gamestate.Level++;
            gamestate.SaveState();
            gamestate.Reset();
            Randomize();
        }
        if (state[(int)Player.Y, (int)Player.X])
        {
            gamestate.Level = 0;
            Randomize();
        }
    }

    Vector2 size_to_draw;
    Vector2 position_to_draw;
    Rectangle rectangle_to_draw;
    public void Draw()
    {
        size_to_draw = new Vector2(Cols * 15, Rows * 15);
        position_to_draw = new Vector2((Game1.screen.X - size_to_draw.X) / 2, (Game1.screen.Y - size_to_draw.Y) / 2);
        rectangle_to_draw = new Rectangle((int)position_to_draw.X, (int)position_to_draw.Y, (int)size_to_draw.X, (int)size_to_draw.Y);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle_to_draw, Color.White);

        gamestate.DrawData(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

}

When I take out

```
    if (Player == Destination)
    {
        gamestate.Level++;
        gamestate.SaveState();
        gamestate.Reset();
        Randomize();
    }
    if (state[(int)Player.Y, (int)Player.X])
    {
        gamestate.Level = 0;
        Randomize();
    }
```

from the Apply() method it lets me run the program.
Here is the gamestate class:

```
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Project1
    {
        class GameState
    {
    public float Clock { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Moves { get; set; }

    public List<SaveState> saves = new List<SaveState>();

    public void SaveState()
    {
        saves.Add(new SaveState(Level, Moves, Clock));
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Clock = 0;
        Moves = 0;
    }

    public void DrawData(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < saves.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.font, saves[(saves.Count - 1) - i].String, new Vector2(10, 10 + (30 * i)), Color.White);
        }
    }
}

struct SaveState
{
    public SaveState(int level, int moves, float time)
    {
        Level = level;
        Moves = moves;
        Timestamp = time;

        String = "  Level: " + Level + "   Moves: " + Moves + "   Time: " + Timestamp;
    }

    int Level;
    int Moves;
    float Timestamp;

    public string String;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked for infinite recursion (no exit condition) or indirect infinite recursion in your code?

Comment: When it occurs again, inspect the call stack.

Comment: I would suggest moving `random` to `Game1` as static variable. Initializing the `Random` class without seed in multiple classes can lead to determinism between classes initialized at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomize() calls Apply() and the code you removed from Apply() to make it work calls Randomize().
Since all those (infinite) method calls are pushed on the stack you will eventually get a stack overflow.

Comment: I see, I guess I don't have an eye for noticing recursion in a gameloop. I for some reason thought it wasn't possible, Thank you!